# logrotate create group not working

Tags: suse, logrotate, syslog-ng

cat /etc/issue
Welcome to SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP1 for VMware  (x86_64) - Kernel \r (\l).

rpm -qf /etc/logrotate.conf 
logrotate-3.7.7-10.22

tail -n15 /etc/logrotate.d/syslog
/var/log/mail /var/log/messages {
    compress
    dateext
    maxage 365
    rotate 99
    missingok
    notifempty
    size +4096k
    **create 644 root news** 
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /etc/init.d/syslog reload
    endscript
}

logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/syslog

ls -l /var/log/mail  /var/log/messages
-rw-**r-----** 1 root **root**   0 2015-09-01 13:18 /var/log/mail
-rw-**r-----** 1 root **root** 179 2015-09-01 14:00 /var/log/messages

What is wrong with this configuration file?

Comment: logrotatie is fine, problem is the "/etc/init.d/syslog reload". Files change the group owner by syslog. Еhere is no problem on SUSE 10 with syslog-ng version1.

Answer (score 0):

logrotatie is fine, problem is the "/etc/init.d/syslog reload". Files change the group owner by syslog. There is no problem on SUSE 10 with syslog-ng version1.

My workaround:
add line "chgrp news /var/log/mail /var/log/messages" after "/etc/init.d/syslog reload".